# How do I adjust the volume without pulseaudio?

Tags: sound

I removed PulseAudio from my system following problems with Wine. Now things work well, including Spotify.

However, there is no way to control system volume, although I can control volume inside applications. When I click System->Preferences->Sound, a pop up says "Waiting for sound system to respond" and it gets stuck there.

Is there any alternative that would allow me to adjust system volume?

Comment: Removing `pulseaudio` seems rather extreme action to fix Wine problems. Have you exhausted all other possibilities, such as using a different audio output as suggested [here](http://www.spotify.com/int/help/faq/wine/)?

Comment: Agreed. Just compiling wine with the winepulse patches would fix your sound problems without destroying the sound platform. Sounds hard if you haven't compiled anything but it's actually quite simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type **alsamixer** in terminal to adjust your volume levels.

[image]

**Note:**

- Open your home folder and Press **Ctrl+H** to show hidden folders
- Delete the **.pluse** folder
- Reboot
- Now you can access System>>Preferences>>Sound

Comment: You can also try gnome-alsamixer, which is a graphical interface for alsamixer.